# Aligning a pop-up notice above or below a textbox (CSS/jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, xhtml

I have a password reset page [here](http://pwtest1234.perfmon.com/) that has a jquery popup whenever a user types in the "new password" text box with class `id="pswd_info"`.

The problem is that the pop-up covers the textbox.  Right now I anchored it to the bottom of the page lacking any other solution.  This isn't good when the browser size shrinks as shown below:

[image: Image of PWUpdate screen]

What techniques should I explore to move the pop up down, or the "New Password" textbox up?

Comment: what is id or class of that pop-up, cant find it because it disappears..

Answer (score 1):

You are using this css:

```
right: 360px;
```

this positions that popup 360 pixels from the right end of the page.
this will be problematic since most users have different screen widths. (try yourself by re-sizing your browser's window)

to use a more generic centering method, use this:

```
right:50%;
margin-right:-125px;
```

this will position it in the middle. the margin-right is half of the popup's full width to compensate for the element's own width.

You will have the same problem with your bottom property, hence i suggest using top instead of bottom.
(plus you have 2 different bottom properties, and one is faulty)

Comment: +1 and position:fixed; will do it less bugged too. incase of expanding website and use this form inside div's which got position:relative;

Comment: +1 Horizontal looks much better, though it would be ideal if I can also vertical align, so it only drops down when the user shrinks the height of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

i would move the popup in the same li element as the password input field:

```
<li style="position: relative;">
    <label for="pswd">New Password:</label>
    <span>
        <input id="MainContent_pswd" type="password" autocomplete="off" name="ctl00$MainContent$pswd">
    </span>
    <div id="pswd_info">place your password info box content here...</div>
</li>
```

but you have to set "position: relative" at the li element (either through a class, or as in the example above)

at least you have to set the "bottom: (your bottom distance to the next relative parent)px;" property :)